# Comparing pairs separately for equality, less and greater.

Tags: c++, compare, comparison, std-pair

Lets say that I have a pair of `std::pair<int, int>`s. I want each time I compare them to emit a separate code for equality, less and greater (e.g., 0, -1 and 1 respectively).

The naive approach would be to write some `if`-`else` code:

```
int compare_int_pairs(std::pair<int, int> const &p1_, std::pair<int, int> const &p2_) {
  if(p1_.first < p2_.first) {
    return -1;
  } else if(p1_.first > p2_.first) {
    return 1;
  } else {
     if(p1_.second < p2_.second) {
       return -1;
     } else if(p1_.second > p2_.second) {
       return 1;
     } else {
       return 0;
     }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

But is there a better and more efficient way to do this (e.g., bitwise operations or something else)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't insist on the values -1, 0 and 1 but are also ok with negative, 0 and positive as result, this is the fastest I could come up with:

```
#include <utility>
#include <stdint.h>

int compare_int_pairs(std::pair<int, int> const &p1_, std::pair<int, int> const &p2_) {
    int ret = p1_.first - p2_.first;
    if (ret == 0) ret = p1_.second - p2_.second;
    return  ret;
}
```

Assembly: http://goo.gl/Kx4SP4

Answer (score 3):

`std::pair` already exposes lexicographic ordering through the standard operators, so you can just use them:

```
int compare_int_pairs(std::pair<int, int> const &p1_, std::pair<int, int> const &p2_) {
  if (p1_ < p2_) return -1;
  if (p1_ > p2_) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

You could use a conditional expression for brevity if you really wanted.